# NullPointerException when trying to access string from another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NullPointerException when I try to access a string from another class using a getString() method that I built that simply returns the string.  Here is where I try to use it and where I am getting the exception:

```
public void storeChar(String str)
{
    wordSeed wrdSd = new wordSeed();
    seed = wrdSd.getSeed();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str.contains(seed))
        {
            int temp = str.indexOf(seed, i);
            singleChar.add(str.charAt(temp));
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the string from wrdSd.getSeed() and storing it into seed, but that obviously is just putting null into seed instead of what I want.  Then when I try to use str.contains(seed) it throws the exception.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Simple solution check `wrdSd.getSeed();` why its return `null`

Comment: whats the other class?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The other class is wordSeed.  TGMCians I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: The question is why the .getSeed() is returning null instead of the string I want.

Comment: yes so post the code for that class and maybe we can help solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure before calling `getSeed()`, you initialize it. You can do this in the constructor such that when you create the object `wrdSd`, the `seed` field is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your wordSeed class and see if the initial value is null. If you make an instance of that class (brand new, seeing "wordSeed wrdSd = new wordSeed();"), then when you use .getSeed(), you would have to be getting a hard-coded value.

A couple ways to fix this is to use the same instance of wordSeed that you set to, or using static variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the same instance of wordSeed that you set to"?

Comment: Simply put, when you use the code "wordSeed wrdSd = new wordSeed();", you create an instance of the class wordSeed. For every instance, if you use a setter or getter, it will only work for that individual instance of the class.

Comment: So let's say I have wordSeed seed1, and wordSeed seed2, and that the .getSeed() method initially returns null. If I do seed1.setSeed("Testing") in a method call early on in the code, but then later do seed2.getSeed(), it will return null because it's not from the same instance you set to.

Comment: Okay, I didn't want to make a new instance of the class wordSeed, but when I tried to access it from a different class it said it couldn't be done.  I would rather not make the variable static because I use it in a lot of places and when I tried to do that it made things very complicated.

Comment: If you want to use the same instance in other classes, you would have to pass that instance through a get method in the class you initialized it in. However, if you are using the exact same variable in multiple classes, and it should always be the same, using static might be a better solution.

Comment: I made the string static, and now I am getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with a value of -1 at `singleChar.add(str.charAt(temp));` of the above code.

Comment: That probably means "int temp = str.indexOf(seed, i);" is returning -1, meaning that str doesn't contain seed. Try printing out your variables to see why that is coming up

Answer (score 0):

```
public class  WordSeed  
{
    private String seed;
    public WordSeed()  
    {
    }   

    public String getSeed()  
    {
          return this.seed;
    }
}
```

Is what I imagine your current implementation is you need to add either of these two options:

```
private String seed = "";
```

OR

```
public WordSeed(String seed)  
{   
        if(null==seed)  
        {  
            this.seed="";
        } else
        { 
           this.seed=seed;  
         }
}
```